# React Hook "useNavigate" is called in function "welcome" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and following a tutorial. I want to create a simple welcome page and have the continue button navigate to the next web page. I receive an error message of useNavigate is called in function welcome that is neither a react function component not a custom react hook function.

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { AGREEMENT } from "../navigation/CONSTANTS";
import { Route, useNavigate, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const welcome = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Welcome!! </div>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(AGREEMENT)}>Continue</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default welcome;
```

Comment: Capitalize your component. `const Welcome = () => /* etc */`. The rules-of-hooks lint plugin uses that convention to identify what is a component.

Answer (score 2):

Capitilize function name welcome to Wecome

```
const Welcome = () => { ...  ...  };
export default Welcome;
```